# PHP variables with MySQL (SET '$field' = '$value')

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use PHP variables in a MySQL query like this:

```
$field = "name_of_field";
$value = "new_value";
$sql = "UPDATE table SET '$field' = '$value'";
```

It doesn't work. When I take out the $field var and just use the name of a field it works.

Comment: Remove the quotes in `SET '$field'` it's a column not a value.

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE table SET $field = '$value'";`

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE table SET $field = '$value'";` should work

Comment: [`Notice the amount of upvotes`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574086/php-variables-with-mysql-set-field-value#comment36177596_23574086) you're missing wrap quotes. @Sol Plus, if it's a typo, edit your question using actuals.

Comment: @Sol what's the content of $sql (var_dump would be nice). Do you execute your query?

Comment: Something else is causing this then. You're probably either using wrong DB connection or mix of APIs, not executing query or other. Show FULL code using `xxx` for DB credentials. I take it that you have a column named `name_of_field` or one that you're wanting to use and exists? @Sol

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` plus `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if using `mysqli_` functions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You were right it works when I removed the quotes for $field. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @Sol You can accept any answer below as correct or I can submit with full explanation.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm just curious why I should use backticks or curly braces, is it standard?

Comment: I for one don't use curly braces around column names, they shouldn't be used for it, but for the values themselves. @Sol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the column name.

```
$field = "name_of_field";
$value = "new_value";
$sql = "UPDATE table SET $field = '$value'";
```

or use backticks

```
$field = "name_of_field";
$value = "new_value";
$sql = "UPDATE table SET `$field` = '$value'";
```

Using backticks around column names (*and/or tables*) ensures that you've not used a (mysql) [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) as well as using spaces in between words. This practice is discouraged.

***For example:*** (here are a few examples of reserved words) - try not using those for tables and/or column names, should this happen to occur anytime in the future.

- for
- to
- as
- desc
- is
- *etc*.

For a list of reserved words, consult the following page on `mysql.com`:

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

Example of spaces between words for tables and columns: (while using backticks)

```
SELECT `column one` FROM `my table`
```

which would be valid.

Yet, by using the following

```
SELECT column one FROM my table
```

would produce an error.

It's best to use underscores and not hyphens (*should this also be the case for future development*). Using hyphens is discouraged to use as a word seperator, as SQL will misinterpret the hyphen as a minus sign, in thinking you want to do some form of mathematical problem.

---

**When in development:** (use error reporting)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and the following if using `mysqli_` functions:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

MySQL (error reporting links)

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://www.php.net/mysqli_error

PDO

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Makes sense, but since i'm using a variable the backticks shouldn't matter?

Comment: No it shouldn't matter, just as long as you don't happen to be using an MySQL reserved word which I've outlined in my answer. @Sol

Comment: The value(s) themselves can be a reserved word that's not a problem,  just as long as it's properly formatted. On the other hand, selecting tables and column names using reserved words must be escaped. @Sol

Answer (score 0):

You don't use single quotes around field names, you use backticks `

Comment: It worked when I just removed the quotes. What's the point in using backticks?

Comment: Backticks allow you to escape MySQL keywords (i.e. if you have a column named "group" you will need to address it as `group` as GROUP is a reserved keyword).

Answer (score 0):

Two things wrong.

1. Firstly, you need to wrap your value for `$sql` in quotes.
2. You need to remove the single quotes around `$field`
3. You can wrap `$field` in curly braces **(optional)**

Result:

```
$field = "name_of_field";
$value = "new_value";
$sql   = "UPDATE table SET `{$field}` = '$value'";
```

Comment: It worked when I removed the single quotes around $field. What is the reason for using backticks or curly braces? Is it just a standard?

Comment: The only time you need to use backticks is if you've given a table or column a name of a reserved word or a name with spaces or other special characters in it.  I strongly suggest that you do not use table or column names that require backticking.  You may think it's no big deal to use `\`total count\`` instead of `total_count`, but down the road you will regret it because of the ease of bugs.

Comment: Edited to remove note about using backticks